# How do I connect a TableViewController to my main ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewcontroller

Right now I have:

1. TableViewController - displays a table that is populated with images and has `UITableViewDelegate` methods
2. ViewController- empty except for default `viewDidLoad()` fn

When I run my program, the screen is blank, presumably because my ViewController has nothing in it.

How do I make it so that it displays my TableViewController?

I have a hunch that I should use `prepareForSegue`, but am confused because when does `prepareForSegue` ever get called? I've read it is called before the `viewDidLoad()`. In that case, should I add a `prepareForSegue` function in my ViewController that directs to my TableViewController?

Comment: If you are new to iOS and Swift, I strongly suggest you follow a tutorial either online or the `Developing iOS8 Apps with Swift` from Stanford on iTunes U. The Stanford course will teach you how to write apps and also teach you the basic frameworks. The videos are excellent. It will also save you hours of writing questions on StackOverflow every time you come across a problem because you will never hit those issues in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Click the ViewController in your storyboard, delete it, and then select your table view controller in the storyboard (click the little yellow icon on the left where the three icons appear right above the controller so that there is a blue outline around the controller). In the Attributes inspector in the utilities panel on the right in Xcode, check "Is Initial View Controller". Sounds like you don't need the other view controller at all.

If you want to segue to the table view controller from your view controller, add a button or some other UI control to the view controller, control-drag from that control to your table view controller, and then select a segue type. `prepareForSegue()` is called right before segueing; it's a way for you second view controller (in your case your table view controller) to get data that it may need from the first view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the root view controller in the app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. Something like:

```
TableViewController *tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = tableViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

should do the trick.